# Getting 404 with AngularJS and mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting 404 as response after sending following request. I have also tried with different API names but still getting the same error.

Backend: Node+Express+Mongoose
Frontend: AngularJs

**Frontend code (AngularJS)**

```
$http.post('http://0.0.0.0:8000/users/supervisors', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Backend code (Mongoose+Mongodb)

```
// Express import
var express = require('express');

// Mongoose import
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Mongoose connection to MongoDB (database: dummydatabase is readonly)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0/dummydatabase', function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

// Mongoose Schema definition
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    parentId: Number
});

// Mongoose Model definition
var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

// Bootstrap express
var app = express();

// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

app.get('/users/supervisors', function (req, res, next) {
    User.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is `app.listen()`?

Comment: Try to change `0.0.0.0` to `localhost`, because 0.0.0.0 is broadcast address and code don't know where to send request.

Comment: Still facing same problem after calling `http://localhost:8000/users/supervisors` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:8000/users/supervisors`.
I have also connected to `mongodb://localhost/dummydatabase`

Comment: Frontend and backend are on the same server?

Comment: yes, both are on same machine but on different ports.
Frontend: 9000
Backend: 8000

Comment: try using http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: 127.0.0.1 same problem.